# unable to create two property with same name in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, polymorphism

I have created two properties with same name but the data type is different.
I am getting this error:

> The type 'Fields' already contains a definition for 'Subject'

Is it possible to overcome this issue?

```
public String Subject
{
     get { return this.subject; }
     set { this.subject = value; }
} 

public AppSettings Subject
{
     get { 
         return this.subjectObj; }
     set { 
         this.subjectObj = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. You would not be able to tell these properties apart when using them. How would you know which property is set in this case?

```
someInstance.Subject = null;
```

The official documentation on [class members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx) states:

> The name of a constant, field, property, event, or type must differ
>   from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

---

**Possible solution:**

Your naming suggests that you may want to create another class `Subject` with at least two properties. (Without more context, I can't say if this is appropriate.)

```
public class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AppSettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

This new class could be used in the original class:

```
public OriginalClass
{
    public Subject subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well in the setter case the compiler *could* decide which property to choose.

Comment: Both `string` and `AppSettings` are nullable. How could it choose?

Comment: Oops! Thanks, @canon.

Comment: You are in fact correct about string being nullable. The the compiler should disallow the call that is ambiguous. In fact if you call a method with two overloads that both accept a nullable but different type the compiler does not disallow the declaration of the methods but the call. `error CS0121`

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't overcome that. Imagine you're doing this line:

```
object myValue = MyClassInstance.Subject;
```

How would it know how to tell them apart? It's better to give them a more appropriate name:

```
public String Subject
{
    get { return this.subject; }
    set { this.subject = value; }
} 

public AppSettings Settings
{
    get { return this.subjectObj; }
    set { this.subjectObj = value; }
}
```

Comment: Actually your reasoning is insufficient. In your case you could tell them apart by the type of 'someValue' much like the way you can tell apart method overloads of setter functions. That's basic polymorphism. The real problem is with the getter part.

Comment: @MrPaulch Fair enough, but if we assign null as the value, then that illustrates the problem better.

Comment: Still insufficient as `String` is not a Nullable type and the second overload is the only match :P The real reason doesn't have to to with the assignment of Properties at all.

Comment: @MrPaulch Okay, that's true in the case of a string type. But if we had two  other types and were doing assignment to null, that would illustrate the issue. But to make the example more clear, I've changed it to use a getter.

Comment: Sorry, I am at fault. string in fact is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot create that. The [C# 4 spec, section 10.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx):and the standards does not allow you do that

> The names of constants, fields, properties, events, or types must
>   differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

On a side note you can refer this thread: [Is there a way to use a property with same name but is of different type in derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055724/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-property-with-same-name-but-is-of-different-type-in-deri)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers seem to put forth the reasoning that polymorphism is not allowed in Properties due to something like:

*How would you resolve this:*

```
MyObject.MyProperty = null;
```

Well that's essentially the same as:

```
MyObject.set_Property(null);
```

Where `set_Property` is a method like:

```
void set_Property(String name) { ... }
void set_Property(AppSettings settings) { ... }
```

This is legal in C#

So `MyObject.MyProperty = null;` can be resolved as:

```
MyObject.set_MyPropert(null);
```

The compiler will report an Error in the line where the call is made, since it could use both overloads.

But `MyObject.set_MyProperty(string.Empty);`
is legal all together.

The reason why C# disallows polymorphism on Properties is the same as why it disallows different return types of functions with the same name.

Illigeal:

```
String get_Property() { return ...; }
AppSettings get_Property() { return ...; }
```

Now if you do `var value = get_Property();` the compiler can not decide which *overload* to use.

So in principle set only properties could be overloaded. The problem arises when you introduce a getter.

I guess for convenience and consistency reasons the standard disallows polymorphism on properties entirely.

Also because in the language context Properties are not *really* considered as methods.